# Segmentation Fault : Core dumped C++ Strings

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, stack

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


string isBalanced(string s) {
    stack<char> take;
    
    for(char c : s){
        if(c == '{' || c == '[' || c == '(')
            take.push(c);
            
        else{
            if(c == '}'){
                if(take.top() == '{')
                    take.pop();
                else
                    return "NO";  
            }
            else if(c == ']'){
                if(take.top() == '[')
                    take.pop();
                else
                    return "NO";  
            }
            else if(c == ')'){
                if(take.top() == '(')
                    take.pop();
                else
                    return "NO";  
            }
        }
    }

    return (take.empty()) ? "YES" : "NO";
}


int main()
{
    cout << isBalanced("[]}") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is basically the brackets balancing function using stack in c++. as I am taking string input of brackets and returning "Yes" or "No" depending on whether it is balanced or not.

but the program gives the error as,
"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"... don't know why!

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior because you are doing a `take.top()` on an empty stack.  The code should check the `take` stack has values before popping.

Comment: @UtsavTayde When you process the `}` at line `if(take.top() == '{'`, you don't have anything in the stack. That's causing the segfault.

Comment: BTW, two aside comments to consider (maybe dispose at your criterium!): 1 - you could treat your 3 types of parens with the same code. E.g. at the beginning of your for loop, if `c` is not one of those 3 types of parens, just continue; then, in the else part, you could just compare the ASCII code of `c` against whatever you have in the stack. 2 - to make the code clearer, it may be better to use constants. E.g. `if(c == open_curly_brace || c == open_square_bracket || c == open_paren)`.

Comment: is there a reason you have to return "YES" or "NO"? a boolean is a much better return value here.

Answer (score 3):

When you hit the `}`, the stack `take` is empty. By using `top()` on the empty stack, you invoke undefined behavior. One potential manifestation of undefined behavior is a segmentation fault.

The solution is to check `take` for being empty before calling `top()`:

```
string isBalanced(string s)
{
    stack<char> take;

    for (char c : s)
    {
        if (c == '{' || c == '[' || c == '(')
            take.push(c);

        else
        {
            if (c == '}')
            {
                if (!take.empty() && take.top() == '{')
                    take.pop();
                else
                    return "NO";
            }
            else if (c == ']')
            {
                if (!take.empty() && take.top() == '[')
                    take.pop();
                else
                    return "NO";
            }
            else if (c == ')')
            {
                if (!take.empty() && take.top() == '(')
                    take.pop();
                else
                    return "NO";
            }
        }
    }

    return (take.empty()) ? "YES" : "NO";
}
```

BTW, when I ran your code, it did not seg fault and output "NO". So you are "lucky" you got the seg fault to alert you to the problem!

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to immediately return NO (or false) in the case where take is empty and a right bracket is detected?

Comment: Oh...... Ya, it should have caught by me. 
anyways... Thank You!

Comment: @dwcanillas: What, have three more `if` and `return "NO";` statements? I don't see that it would be advantageous. I do agree with you that a `bool` return would make more sense, though.

Comment: @FredLarson no, it would be one `if (take.empty()) return false;` at the beginning of the `else` block.  You can sure the string is imbalanced if you ever get a right while the stack is empty.

Comment: No, because it might be another character besides a bracket (though the example string doesn't have any of those.)

Comment: ah sure.   If we skip non-bracket characters right away (suggested in the comments under the question) what I was saying would work.  But what you have is great.  sorry